# Enabled groups only appear if "Disabled" check box is checked

Tags: groups

Several of my groups disappeared today.  When I click on the "Disabled" check box on the "Manage groups" page they appear.  Clicking on "more" only shows the "disable" and "delete" options.  If I uncheck the "Enabled" check box all groups disappear.  If I go to the "Manage Groups" page click the "Disabled" check box they appear, if I uncheck the "Disabled" check box, they stay on the page.
I have tried clearing the cache.

Comment: edit: do you have access to your db - if so take a look in log_civicrm_group and it may have some hints as to what has happened

Comment: Do you mean the table civicrm_group?  There is no table called log_civicrm_group.  All the groups have is_active = 1 and is_hidden = 0.  Anything else I should look at?

Comment: Guess that means you don't have Logging on

Comment: Are the problem ones all Smart Groups?

Comment: I do not have smart groups.